# Can a regular expression be used for getting a substring?

Tags: java, regex, substring

I'm writing some code Java FX code where I evaluate which button is being clicked, so I need to compare the id of the `getSource` string.

I'm always getting strings like:

> Button[id=playButton, styleClass=button]
>   Button[id=pauseButton, styleClass=button]
>   Button[id=stopButton, styleClass=button]
>   Button[id=nextButton, styleClass=button]

So according to which button is being clicked I perform some statements. I was using a set of `if` and `else if`'s evaluating `contains(id)` where id would play, pause, stop and next.

I'd like it better to use a switch so every case would be play, pause, stop and next. 
How can I get a subString, getting only any of either play, pause, stop or next?

Comment: I think the string you are getting is the `toString()` representation of the button, so instead you can use `Button` instance itself to compare?

Comment: I'm using ActionEvent.getSource().toString()

Comment: It would be possible to create regex to get button id, but unfortunately, I don't know how to build it. But I believe that in JavaFX, you can directly access button's `id` and you could just use Java's [String.startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) and see which of 4 buttons is it. If you're doing a lot of comparisons this would be even faster method than regexes, but if not, regex is surely more elegant way to do it:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need regex, when a simple indexOf("id="), lastIndexOf ("Button,") and subString of the previous two calls would work just fine?